# Application error on heroku - No 'composer.json' found

Tags: php, heroku

When I try to access my heroku page it says

> "Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details"

This is my build log:

> PHP app detected ! WARNING: No 'composer.json' found. Using
>   'index.php' to declare app type as PHP is considered legacy
>   functionality and may lead to unexpected behavior. Bootstrapping...
>   Installing platform packages... NOTICE: No runtime required in
>   composer.lock; using PHP ^5.5.17 apache (2.4.20) nginx (1.8.1) php
>   (5.6.30) Installing dependencies... Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10
>   09:29:45 Preparing runtime environment... NOTICE: No Procfile, using
>   'web: heroku-php-apache2'. Checking for additional extensions to
>   install... Discovering process types Procfile declares types -> web
>   Compressing... Done: 13.9M Launching... Released v119 deployed to
>   Heroku Build finished Blogs Careers Documentation
>
> ========================================================================

Comment: The obvious first question is: do you have a `composer.json` somewhere in your project?

Comment: no, but it had run successfully some days ago, suddenly it's showing this error..

Comment: I looked around and this appears to be a normal log when Composer is not used. What does your _application_ log say when you try to reach the site?

Comment: it says build succeeded, but i didnt use proper database . does it cause this problem?

Comment: Probably, yes..

Comment: ooops ! ok i'll try to connect another database thank you :)

Comment: If you figure it out, post an answer here and mark it accepted.

Comment: Ever figured this out?