# How can I deploy static web app on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I followed instructions from an answer of a similar topic(https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531897/4388482). Well, my app is getting deployed on Heroku but it doesn't work good. I'm getting the following warning

> Your project only contains an 'index.php', no 'composer.json'.
>   Using 'index.php' to declare app type as PHP is deprecated and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Do I need to install something maybe?

---

**UPDATE**

Project structure was initially this:

[image: Project structure was initially this]

I did the following:

- Installed **PHP 5** and **composer**.
- I renamed *package.json* to *composer.json* and removed *package-lock.json*.
- Typed "composer update" command. I got "nothing to install or update" message.
- Added vendor to gitignore. Pushed changes to heroku.

I got the following warnings

1. > Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!
2. > Composer vendor dir found in project!

Comment: If you haven't searched for the error on the Inernet yet, have a look at (1st) https://stackoverflow.com/q/44683097/1415724 and the 2nd search result found https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php - There were more hits, so you might want to continue on from there.

Comment: I've done some research. Initially I hadn't installed neither php or composer. I followed heroku instructions and installed them both but still the website doesn't work good. I have php 5, but I that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate "doesn't work good" more?

Comment: The UI isn't as it is locally. Scrolldown pages don't work

Comment: `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are likely to be JavaScript dependencies. Rename them back to how they were, and don't delete the lock file. You always need the lock file for a repeatable deployment. Are the files in your `vendor` folder committed to the repo? I suspect you need to fix that - remove them from the repo and add a `composer.json` file (and the lock file) to install them using Composer.

Comment: @halfer composer.json and composer.lock would be empty right?

Comment: I cant find the dependencies. Shouldn't they exist in package.json file?
https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume

Comment: I have added an answer below. Would you add your `package.json` contents to your question, in an update at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complaint that Heroku has is [regarding this folder](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume/tree/master/vendor).

For the record, the contents of this folder presently are:

```
bootstrap
fontawesome-free
jquery-easing
jquery
```

What has happened here is that someone has committed dependencies to your version control, which is not good practice. It will work as is, but it is not very easy to do upgrades, especially since you cannot easily see what versions you currently do have.

There are three ways to go about this.

1. Decide if these are PHP dependencies, by searching [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). There *is* a Composer dependency for Bootstrap, but you would need to see if the version you are using is available (or whether you can upgrade to one that is available).
2. Decide if these are JavaScript dependencies, by searching [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). I wonder if it is worth examining the contents of your `package.json` in case these are already covered. For what it is worth, I would generally consider these candidates for JavaScript libraries rather than PHP, but do what works for you.
3. Choose to leave these dependencies committed in the existing `vendor` folder. It will work, but it is not ideal for the reasons already stated.

In the last two cases, you could probably get away with a `composer.json` file thus, which you should commit to the repo:

```
{
  "require": {
  }
}
```

You could try a `composer install` after this, to see if it will generate a `.lock` file on an empty dependency list. If this does generate, then you should commit this also.

Comment: Option 3 would be the best because I don't mind for future upgrades. In that case do I need to commit the vendor folder?

Comment: Yes, if you go for option 3, then leave the `vendor` folder as it is, and try to get the minimal `composer*` files committed.

Comment: When i type "composer install" I'm getting "Nothing to install or update", and "generating autoload files" messages. Then, on heroku build I'm getting the "composer dir found" warning.

Comment: You may get away without the lock file (since there is nothing to lock). I wonder if there are Heroku settings to turn off the directory error behaviour, since it is not disastrous in itself for a PHP project to have a committed `vendor` folder. If there is no such option, rename `vendor` to anything else (e.g. `myvendors`) and repair all the things in the project that refer to this).

Comment: Finally it worked! Thanks, you spent so much time helping me.

Comment: Lovely, well done @Antony. If you feel there are any things you learned that would be useful for future readers (e.g. how to turn off errors in Heroku) then you are welcome to add an additional self-answer here. The more information we can create for other people the better. `:=)`